# Python script sorted csv files exported empty

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

My current csv file

Client.csv:

```
RecNo,AdultNo,NoChild,ClientName,CAT  
1,1,5,Fred Flintstone,0  
2,10,2,Georia OKeefe,5  
3,2,4,Joe BLow,6  
4,2,5,Cher,0
```

Output desired is group by NoChild, then sort ascending by ClientName then export groups to separate csv files.

Thus for the Client.csv file I would have

1.csv - empty

2.csv
2,10,2,Georia OKeefe,5

3.csv - empty

4.csv
3,2,4,Joe BLow,6

5.csv
4,2,5,Cher,0
1,1,5,Fred Flintstone,0

I get all 5 csv files, but their empty. What am I missing?

Below is my Python 2.7 code:

```
import csv

counter = ("1","2","3","4","5")
for variablefile  in counter:
    inputCSVFile = "C:\\Test\\Client.csv"
    variable_CSV = "C:\\Test\\" + variablefile + ".csv"

    with open(variable_CSV , 'wb') as f:
        with open(inputCSVFile) as test:
            reader = csv.DictReader(test)
            for row in reader:
                mylist = tuple([row["NoChild"] for row in reader])
                print mylist
                if mylist == variablefile:
                    print mylist
                    f.write((sorted("ClientName")) + '\n')
                else:
                    exit
```

I've been hacking away at various syntax's but get the same results. What am I missing here? Please provide code suggestions if you have solution. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that `mylist == variablefile` ever returns `True` since `mylist` is a `tuple` and `variablefile` is a string as far as I can tell.

This also explains why you don't get a `TypeError` when you try add a list to a string:

```
(sorted("ClientName")) + '\n'
```

And, `sorted("ClientName")` will return

```
['C', 'N', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 't']
```

which probably isn't what you meant either ...